# How to determine what particular service does an svchost process represent?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, task-manager, svchost

When I open Windows Task manager and look at the Processes tab I can see numerous svchost.exe processes and one of them uses to produce serious and continuous CPU load from time to time. Needless to say I am quite curious what particular service this actually is. Is it possible to determine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is click on the particular instance of svchost.exe you want to examine, right-click on it, and then choose "Go to service(s)". It'll take you to the appropriate service from there.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to achieve this:

1) In command prompt, type `tasklist /SVC`

2) The other way is to right click on it (within task manager) and select Go To Services

When you know what it is, check it out online and then disable if safe to do so!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a 3rd party tool, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can show you the services simply by hovering over the actual .exe file. It'll do the same thing for just about any .exe that hosts a service.